# Create an acess point with netplan

Tags: 18.04, raspberrypi, netplan

I am trying to set up a wireless access point on my raspberry pi 3B (running Ubuntu 18.04 server) using netplan. The documentation seems to imply that I can do this by specifying `mode: ap` in the .yaml configuration file for netplan (located in /etc/netplan folder). However, when trying to apply the netplan, I get the following error: `wlan0: netowrkd does not support wifi in access point mode`. I know for a fact that the adapter itself supports AP mode, since I've successfully used it before using a slightly different procedure that involved purging netplan and using hostapd directly. I would like to stick with netplan this time because this way I can easily switch between AP and managed modes by switching out the .yaml file. Is there any way I can get past this error?

Comment: How did you set the AP on netplan? I can't find how to put `passphrase`, `ap_isolate`, etc.

Comment: In the 50-cloud-init.yaml file (or equivalent in /etc/netplan), after "wifis", "wlan0", and "dhcp4", on the next line I have:
'access-points:
    "SSID"
        mode: ap
        password: "PASSWORD"
        mode: ap'
Indentation is 4 spaces where applicable.

Comment: While I tried to format the comment, commenting time ran out. Here's the proper formatting:
`dhcp4: true
 access-points:
     "piRobot":
         password: "181081Robot"
         mode: ap`
Edit: ok formatting still won't show up in code. Anyway, "access points" on same line as "dhcp4", then next line, 4 spaces right is SSID, then next line 4 spaces right is "ap password", then "mode" is on next line, no spaces.

Comment: Could you please answer me here: https://askubuntu.com/q/1166619/814? Please include your source of reference, I'd like to see all the settings available to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented in `netplan(5)`:

```
ap is only supported with NetworkManager.
```

You must specify `renderer: NetworkManager` and install the network-manager package to put a wifi interface in ap mode with netplan, because as stated, this is not implemented with the networkd backend.

Comment: Yep, thank you. Just found that solution.