# Define hostapd configuration settings on netplan

Tags: netplan, network-bridge, hostapd

I recently discovered that netplan can manage hostapd accesspoints, but this is the extent of the example config:

```
    wlp1s0:
      access-points:
        "guest":
           mode: ap
           # no WPA config implies default of open
```

I can find no other documentations of how to define other settings like WPA security and passphrase. I need the following `hostapd.conf` settings defined and EAP in the future as well:

```
interface=wlo1
bridge=br0
hw_mode=g
channel=0
ieee80211d=1
country_code=AE
ieee80211n=1
wmm_enabled=1

ssid=SSID
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK 
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_passphrase=*********
```

I am aware netplan requires NetworkManager for access point configuration, and I don't know if keeping the bridge managed by `networkd` will hinder the bridging. If possible, please clarify this point as well.

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/netplan/blob/master/doc/netplan.md) perhaps what you're looking for? I believe it lists all the possible arguments and defaults for netplan.

Comment: @anvoice, do you mean to say `key-management` and `psk` are the only thing from `hostapd.conf` I can define on netplan?

Comment: I'm not a Linux guru, so I could be wrong on this, but the documentation claims that defining an AP using netplan creates an AP using hostapd. Wouldn't that mean it using your hostapd.conf file internally, thus defining the proper channel, etc.?

Comment: @anvoice, yes it most definitely does, but if I can't modify them, I need to at least know the defaults. Plus, its apparent inability to do things like add EAP controllers means it's pretty much useless save for the most basic operations.

Answer (score 0):

According to the manpage, AP is only supported with the NetworkManager renderer. You should have a line in the netplan that tells it to use NetworkManager for the configuration of that device, then configure it there.

```
wlp1s0:
  access-points:
    "guest":
       mode: ap
       renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: Yes, I know, that's I said in my last line. What I want to ask is how to configure it, how do I set the passphrase, operating modes, etc. What are the defaults?

Comment: Line `renderer: NetworkManager` should be under block `wlp1s0:`

Answer (score 0):

You can run it manually in a startup script.

- In `/etc/crontab` add:

  ```
  @reboot root /root/startup &
  ```
- In `/root/startup` add:

  ```
  ip addr add 192.168.1.1/24 dev wlp2s0
  hostapd -Bi wlp2s0 /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
  ```
- And in `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` add:

  ```
  subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.100;
    option routers 192.168.1.1;
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
    authoritative;
  }
  ```

Alternatively, you can configure a static IP on the client.